# PHP MVC - Como executar métodos do Model?

Tags: php, mvc, controller, view, model

Boa tarde!

Como faço para executar um método da classe Model, em especifico um método de inserção ao BD, no caso preciso enviar os dados do Formulário.

Esse é o formulário na View (setor.php):

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     <div class="form-group">
          <label for="nomesetor">Nome do setor:</label>
          <input id="nomesetor" name="nomesetor" type="text" class="form-control col-12 col-sm-12">
     </div>

     <a href="<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>" class="btn btn-danger">Cancelar</a>
     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Cadastrar</button>
</form>
```

O método que preciso executar no Model (Setor.php) é esse:

```
public function addSetor ($nome) {
    $sql = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO setor SET nomesetor = :nome");
    $sql->bindValue(":nome", $nome);
    $sql->execute();
}
```

Enfim, ao clicar no button CADASTRAR, preciso executar esse método enviando o formulário. Eu preciso passar pelo controller? E o form, envio através de alguma URL na action?

Fico no aguardo, agradeço por qualquer ajuda.

Comment: Sim, essa é a função do controller no MVC.

Comment: Acredito que essa questão seja duplicata

Comment: Entendi a questão de passar pelo Controller. Mas, como passo os dados do formulário como parâmetros do método?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para passar os dados como parâmetro no método desejado basta, setar uma action no seu formulário para o arquivo, onde contem o Controller que tem acesso ao Seu Model.

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="caminho/seuController.php">
```

No seu Controller você pode verificar a variavel $_POST com os dados do formulário e fazer a chamada do seu método passando os valores como parâmetros.

```
if(isset($_POST['nomesetor']) && ! empty($_POST['nomesetor'])){
    $nomeSetor = $_POST['nomesetor']; /*não esqueça de escapar as informações por segurança ao inserir no banco de dados*/

    $this->addSetor($nomeSetor);
}
```

Espero ter ajudado :)

Comment: Mén! Muito boa e segura sua resposta.